# how subscribe to first route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Here is my router:

```
Routes = [
  { path: 'immeuble', component: ImmeubleComponent ,children:[
    { path: ':id', children: [ { path: 'general',loadChildren: '...'}]
    },
    { path: '', pathMatch:'full', component:AccueilComponent }, //when in url we have /immeuble this is called
  ]},
];
```

What I try: subscribe to `params['id']` inside `.ts` file of `ImmeubleComponent`

So my .ts file of ImmeubleComponent looks like:

```
this.activatedRoute.firstChild.params.subscribe(
      p => {
        console.log(p);
      }
    )
```

But this subscribe only once when I refresh page, why ?
If I go to `/immeuble` my `p=undefined`
If I type in url `/immeuble/2/general`, I get well `p=2`

But this match only when I come on page, when I navigate across my app with `router.navigate()` 
My subscribption isn't emitted?

Here I want from `ImmeubleComponent` subscribe to changement of  my id ? How achieve?

### Update

add firstChild.params

Comment: Can you reproduce in a Plunker? Plunker provides a ready-to-use Angular2 template.

Comment: sorry I spend 45mn to do my plunker here you are https://plnkr.co/edit/sI3jLzsgNCMzeAVa6tcb?p=info I only use these file `app-routing.module.ts` and `aaa.ts` and `bbb.ts` and `cccnavigation.ts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need to subscribe again to the `firstChild.params` after each navigation probably because you are navigating away from this child route. If you wouldn't use `back` between these routes, then I assume it would work with `firstChild.params.subscribe` alone.

This might work for you though

```ts
constructor(router:Router, activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) {
  router.events.filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe(e => {
    console.log('params', activatedRoute.firstChild.snapshot.params);
  });
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/tckgJIwsmI1Lq5HqDBEM?p=preview)

Comment: yes but I subscribe in ImmeubleComponent  not in other root level? I don't understand here I have always /immeuble

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what the expected behavior is?

Comment: Can you check my updated post... I'm always in /immeuble my immeublecomponent.html have only `<router-outlet>` I want in my immeublecomponent.ts subscribe to firstChild  acitvatedRoute.